# Select Range from current cell to 7 next visible cells (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I've filtered a range with only the visible cells. I have a For Each loop which in each loop should make the cell bold + the next 6 visible cells in the bold in the column.

I accidently first made it with .Offset but obviously it also took into account the filtered cells. How do I select a range within my rng based on my current cell in the For loop and the next 6 elements/cells?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` but the hard part is to know what range to give it, so that you will get back exactly 7. You could loop through, adding one cell at a time until you get back 7, but that is indirect and slow. A better way is to just check if each cell is hidden until you find 7 that aren't.

I made a function that takes a range, and returns that range and the next 6 not-hidden cells below it.

```vb
Sub Example()
    AndTheNext6(Range("A1")).Font.Bold = True
End Sub

Function AndTheNext6(StartFrom As Range) As Range
    Dim r As Integer, Count As Integer
    r = StartFrom.Row
    Dim SelectRange As Range
    Set SelectRange = StartFrom
    While Count < 6 And r < StartFrom.Parent.Rows.Count
        r = r + 1
        If StartFrom.Parent.Rows(r).Hidden = False Then
            Set SelectRange = Union(SelectRange, StartFrom.Parent.Cells(r, StartFrom.Column))
            Count = Count + 1
        End If
    Wend
    Set AndTheNext6 = SelectRange
End Function
```